# django pagination not working with django filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a `ListView` page that is working well with pagination. I also have Django filter added to that page for filtering. The problem is pagination is working well but with Django filter it stops working. When the page loads `paginate_by` is not working. When the pagination is clicked the next page not working.

What am I doing wrong?

views.py

```
class JobsListView(ListView, FilterView):
# model = JobPost
queryset = JobPost.objects.all()
template_name = 'jobpost_list.html'
paginate_by = 3
# page_kwargs = 'page'
filterset_class = JobPostFilter

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.kwargs:
        return JobPost.objects.filter(position=self.kwargs['position']).order_by('-created_at')
    else:
        query = JobPost.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
        return query

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['todays'] = date.today()
    context['filter'] = JobPostFilter(self.request.GET,  queryset=self.get_queryset())
    return context
```

template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load fontawesome %}
{% block content %}
  {% if messages %}
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show">
{% for m in messages %}
<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ m }}</li>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
{% endfor %}
</div>
 {% endif %}
<div class="col-12">
    <h1 class="text-center">Vacancies</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
 <form method="get">

     {% bootstrap_form filter.form %}
     {% buttons %}
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search {% fontawesome_icon 
 'search' %}</button>
     {% endbuttons %}
  </form>

</div>

<div class="col-8">

  {% for job in filter.qs %}
  <div class="joblists">
  <h3><a href='{% url "jobpost_detail" job.slug %}'>{{ job.position }} </a> <a 
  href="{% url 'jobpost_update_form' job.slug %}">{% fontawesome_icon 'edit' %}  
  </a></h3>
  <p>{{ job.description|safe|truncatewords:30 }}</p>
  {% if job.location != '' %}
   <p>{% fontawesome_icon 'location-arrow' %} <strong>{{ job.location }} 
   </strong> 
   </p>
   {% endif %}
 <p>{{ job.job_type }}</p>
  {% if job.deadline != NULL and job.deadline > todays %}
    <p>{% fontawesome_icon 'calendar' %} {{ job.deadline|timeuntil }} <small>to 
  deadline</small></p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if job.deadline > todays %}
  <p>{% fontawesome_icon 'check-circle' color='green' %} Open</p>
  {% elif job.deadline < todays %}
  <p>{% fontawesome_icon 'times-circle' color='red' %} Closed</p>
  {% endif %}
 </div>
 {% endfor %}

</div>

<div class="pagination">

{% if is_paginated %}
 <hr>
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
 <ul class="pagination justify-content-center pagination-sm">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      {% if not search %}
      <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="{% url 'jobpost_list' %}?page={{ 
          page_obj.previous_page_number }}" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="{% url 'jobpost_list' %}?{{search}}&page= 
     {{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <li class="page-item disabled">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for object in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{% url 'jobpost_list' 
     %}?page={{ forloop.counter }}">{{ forloop.counter }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      {% if not search %}
      <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="{% url 'jobpost_list' %}?page={{ 
         page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
      </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="{% url 'jobpost_list' %}?{{search}}&page=      
    {{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <li class="page-item disabled">
        <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
  </nav>
 {% endif %}


</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

in `{% for job in filter.qs %}` if you replace `filter.qs` with 'object_list' it pagination and filtering will work. BUT This won't have any records when the page loads initially without any filter params set in the url.

I am trying to figure out what can be done. Searching....

Comment: I solved it by changing filter.qs to object_list since i was using FIlterview and getting rid of def get_queryset

Comment: I tried what i mentioned above but I don't get results initial when there has been no filtering done.

Is that working for you?

Comment: Yes. add this Strict = False in your views.py

Comment: Where exactly? I put it in my `FilterView` but it didn't work.

Comment: from https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/930

The immediate work around is to set strict = False on your filterset. This has consequence that actual invalid filter parameters will lead to partial filtering rather than showing empty results, but it should be workable for the now. (Better is to override the view get logic of course...)

We'll have a think and improve the handling for the unbound case.

Comment: I hope you are aware of the consequences. I think, I will just add a random param to the link so that it loads data. like `?a=1`.

Comment: Yes and make sure you have Class Jobs(FilterView), not class Jobs(ListView, FilterView). It worked for me

Comment: Also, what you mentioned worked. It was `strict` instead of 'Strict`.